# CSS isn't applying into HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been given HTML ready to go, now I have been tasked to create the CSS for it. Before I properly start I think my CSS is not applying into my HTML. I don't know if its the way I linked it but I have checked.
This is the HTML

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    color: #C8E5E3;
}
.body {
    background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <!-- Exercise2.html An HTML web page with CSS
     -->

    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
      <title>Jake's Coffee Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jakecss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1> Jake's Coffee Shop </h1>
    
      <a href="Exercise2.html">Home</a>
      <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
      <a href="music.html">Music</a>
      <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
      <p>Come in and experience...</p>
      <img src="coffee.jpg" alt="coffee cup" width="200" height="200">
      <ul>
        <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
        <li>Freshly made sandwiches</li>
        <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
        <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
        <li>Open mic nights</li>
        <li> ... </li>
      </ul>
      <p>23 Pine Road<br> Nottingham, NG1 5YU <br> 0115 9324567</p>
      <p> Copyright &copy; 2011 Jake's Coffee House<br>
      <a href="mailto:jake@jcoffee.com">jake@jcoffee.com</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hey you have not used header class name in html markup.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any tags that use your `header` class.

`.body` looks for a class that's called `body`. To decorate your `<body>` tag, you need to do it like this:

```
body { 
    background-color: powerblue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `header` html tag.

For tags part of html the css is applied by using

`header {
//some value
}`

For class attributes it's

`.header_class {
//some value
}`

For tags it's

`#header_tag {
//some value
}`

So your body is a html tag and should be

`body {
background-color: grey;
}`